# Selenium does not respond to electron desktop app alert dialog

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

I am automating a ReactJS electron application (webapp and the desktop app) using Selenium and Java. Because the desktop app contains the same webapp code behind the scenes, I can reuse my Selenium code to test the Desktop app using remote webdriver. The application displays a dialog box upon successful login. I tried using Selenium's  alert.accept() as well as Robot enter key event but it does not work for the modal dialog of the Desktop app.

Example the following code works when I run against the webapp but fails at this point for the desktop app:

public static String getAlertText(WebDriver webDriver) {
`Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
return alert.getText();`

}

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion but it doesn't work. The program gets stuck in to infinite search. See code below as per your suggestion:

  public static String getAlertText(WebDriver webDriver) {
    Alert alert = new WebDriverWait(webDriver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
//    Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
    return alert.getText();
  }